# Xamarin UITableView animation starts from wrong position

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation, xamarin.ios, xamarin

In my View I have one `UILabel` and one `UITableView`.

I want them to animate downwards by 40 pixels. The following is my code

```
        var newFrame = newsStand.Frame;
            newFrame = new CGRect (newsStand.Frame.X, newsStand.Frame.Y+40, newsStand.Frame.Width, newsStand.Frame.Height);
            UIView.BeginAnimations ("slideAnimation");
            UIView.SetAnimationDuration (2);
            UIView.SetAnimationCurve (UIViewAnimationCurve.EaseInOut);
            UIView.SetAnimationDelegate (this);
            UIView.SetAnimationDidStopSelector (new Selector ("slideAnimationFinished"));
            nfloat newY=searchLabel.Center.Y+40;
            searchLabel.Center = new  CGPoint (searchLabel.Center.X, newY);
            newsStand.Frame =  newFrame;
            UIView.CommitAnimations ();
```

`newsStand` is my `UITableView` instance and `searchLabel`, `UILabel` instance. When this code is executed, `searchLabel` animates as expected by moving down 40 pixels. But `newsStand` jumps 40 pixels upwards initially and animates to its original position. I have tried setting center (like I have done for `searchLabel`) of `newsStand` instead of Frame also. But the result is same. What is causing this behaviour ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is very complex. You can greatly simplify the animation by using `UIView.Animate()` instead:

```
var myLabel = new UILabel (new CGRect (100, 100, 100, 40))
{ 
    Text = "Animate me!",
    TextColor = UIColor.Yellow
};
window.Add (myLabel);

UIView.Animate (
    duration: 0.5,
    animation: () => myLabel.Center = new CGPoint (myLabel.Center.X, myLabel.Center.Y + 40),
    completion: () => {}
);
```